# Subdomain Vs Subdirectory for different languages

Tags: seo, subdomain, internationalization, multi-subdomains, domain-authority

We have a news site in English and what we are doing now is launching the new version of the same news site in different languages. These news sites are supposed to be linked to our parent news site but they will have unique content in it i.e. they are not only just localized versions of the parent site but they will be new sites in terms of content and news too.

What we are having trouble concluding is that, though we have heard that google treats both the practices the same i.e. subdirectories and subdomains but if we have let's say es.ournewssite.com, will this subdomain add SEO value and add to the domain authority of our parent news site i.e. ournewssite.com?

We want to obtain a better domain authority and better SEO value by launching the different language versions in subdomains, are we on the right path or are we missing something here?

Comment: I recommend subdomains for languages so that you can move the hosting closer to the people who speak that language. There is no difference as far as domain authority or SEO goes as to what you choose.

Comment: You should use the correct terminology. It is "directories" and not the Windows user concept of "folders" which is often used for other user interfaces, too, but is not the same thing as a directory when discussing operating system and web layout and architecture.

Comment: Thanks Rob, fixed the terminology.